# How to see that the topology of a topological vector space is entirely determined by a neighbourhood basis of the origin

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

I have a question regarding the property of topological vector spaces $X$ that their topology is completely determined by the neighbourhood system of any point $x\in X$ (and therefore in particular by the neighbourhood system of the origin.

Translations in a tvs are continuous which means that it maps open sets to open sets.

1.) Does that already imply that when I have an open set $U\subseteq X$ and translate that by an element $x\in X$, that $U+x$ is also open? I am not certain because the translation is defined pointwise: $T_{x_0}(x)= x+x_0$. So can I conclude that if I do that pointwise translation for any element in $U$ that the set $\{x+x_0|x\in U\}$ is again an open set? Or do I have to prove anything here?

2.) How does the fact that open sets are translated to open sets tell me that neighbourhoods are mapped to neighbourhoods? A neighbourhood is a set $V\subseteq X$ that contains an open set $U\subseteq X$. But how do I know what happens with all the elements of the neighbourhood $V$ that do not belong to the open set $U$ that is contained in $V$?

3.) How can I now show that the neighbourhood system of the origin somehow is a basis for the topology? I.e., how does a neighbourhood basis relate to a basis or subbasis of the topology?

Answer (score 2):

> Translations in a tvs are continuous which means that it maps open sets to open sets.

No, continuous functions don't have to map open sets to open sets. The fact that it works for translations is because translations are **homeomorphisms**, which is a lot stronger condition than just continuous. And indeed, homeomorphisms map open subsets to open subsets.

A translation $x\mapsto x+x_0$ is a homeomorphism because it has a (continuous) inverse $x\mapsto x-x_0$.

And the other important property of translations is that for any $x,y\in X$ there is a translation that maps $x$ to $y$. And this pretty much means that topology around any point is the same.

More generally, spaces with the property that for any $x,y\in X$ there is a homeomorphism mapping $x$ to $y$ are called [homogeneous spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space) and indeed they have this nice property that they look the same wherever you are. Thus what we see here is that topological vector spaces are homogenous.

Its like a weird planet, wherever you land everything looks the same. To the point that you can't really tell where you are. Sounds bad, but for mathematicians it is good, because the space behaves better in some sense.

> So can I conclude that if I do that pointwise translation for any element in $U$ that the set $\{x+x_0|x\in U\}$ is again an open set? Or do I have to prove anything here?

Everything in maths has to be proven. Yes, it is correct. But not because translation is continuous, but because it is a homeomorphism.

> But how do I know what happens with all the elements of the neighbourhood $V$ that do not belong to the open set $U$ that is contained in $V$?

And what is supposed to happen to them? They are irrelevant. They are mapped somewhere, but they don't matter much for the definition of neighbourhood.

Also you should pay attention to the definition of "neighbourhood". Because some authors by "neighbourhood" mean "open neighbourhood", which is easier to work with. In particular when we say that neighbourhoods form a topology then we mean open neighbourhoods.

> How can I now show that the neighbourhood system of the origin somehow is a basis for the topology?

It is not. The statement "the neighbourhood system of the origin **determines** the basis" means that any open subset arises somehow from neighbourhoods of the origin. And this "somehow" in this case means "by translation". So for example, if $(-11, -9)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then we can write it as $(-1,1)-10$ and $(-1,1)$ is a neighbourhood of the origin $0$. And so the knowledge of neighbourhoods of $0$ is enough to determine any open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, even though most of them obviously don't contain $0$.

Note that this is not necessarily true for other spaces. For example consider the closed interval $[0,1]$. Neighbourhoods of $0$ don't determine neighbourhoods of say $1/2$ and vice versa. This space is not homogenous, and indeed, every homeomorphism $[0,1]\to [0,1]$ has to map $\{0,1\}$ to $\{0,1\}$. Meaning $0$ and $1$ differ substantially from other points. Which is intuitively clear: these are ends of $[0,1]$ after all, so they have to be special. But now you have this intuition formalized.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have some questions to your answer though:
1.) How can I see that there is always a translation that  maps $x$ to $y$ for any $x,y \in X$?
2.) How can I then prove that open sets $\{x+x_0|x\in U\}$ is again an open set?
3.) I always talking of the more general notion of neighbourhoods. So how can a neighbourhood be translated to an open set? Since  neighbourhood can also possible be a closed set.

Comment: @guest1 1) translation that maps $x$ to $y$ is $f(v)=v-x+y$. 2) because translation is a homeomorphism. And so it has continuous inverse $f^{-1}$. And continuous means "preimage of open is open", and preimage of $f^{-1}$ is $(f^{-1})^{-1}=f$. And so $f$ maps open to open. 3) that depends on the definition. And context. If someone says "neighbourhoods form a basis of topology" then neighbourhood has to be open, there's no other choice. And so they are thinking about more strict definition. Sorry, there's no concrete answer to this one.

Comment: Ok thanks again. Let me rephrase my last question. In the book of Schäfer he writes: "Such a topology is completely
determined by the neighborhood filter of any point $\in L$, in particular by the
neighborhood filter of 0." He defined neighbourhoods in the general way. So how does the neighbourhood system of 0 determine the topology on that t.v.s.? I understand it as once you have the nighbourhood system of 0 you can construct the open sets from that. How can I do that?

Comment: @guest1 right, so this can indeed be done for general definition as well. You can recover open sets from neighbourhoods as follows: a subset $O\subseteq X$ is open if and only if for any $x\in O$ we have that $O$ is a (general) neighbourhood of $x$.